# What does Node * head outside of the struct do?

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

So I have the class LinkedList. Can someone explain why node * head is outside of the struct and node * next, prev are inside the struct? What is the purpose of this and how does it differ from the others? thanks

```
class LinkedList
{
public:
        LinkedList();
        ~LinkedList();

        void add(char ch);
        bool find(char ch);
        bool del(char ch);
        void display(
private:
        struct node
        {
                char data;
                node * next;
                node * prev;          
        };
        node *head;
};
```

Comment: I think you should re-read the part about linked lists on whatever book you're using. Or be a bit more explicit in what you don't understand about this.

Comment: To access the first element, you need the head. Remember that the whole class is your LinkedList, not only the struct. The struct is only one element in the LinkedList, which points to the previous and next element (therefore is a double linked list) and contains the data

Comment: `head` is not part of the `struct node` definition. Each node does not have a `head` of its own. `head` is a pointer to an instance of a the `struct node` and represents the pointer to the linked list which consists of 0 or more nodes.

Comment: Look at the code. The constructor for `LinkedList` will probably look similar to this: `LinkedList::LinkedList() : head(nullptr) {}` and then look at what happens in `add()`.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
    struct node
    {
            char data;
            node * next;
            node * prev;          
    };
```

is an inner declaration of a structure type within a class.

This

```
node *head;
```

is a declaration of a data member of the type `struct node *` of the class `LinkedList`. To make it more clear rewrite the list definition the following way

```
struct node
{
        char data;
        node * next;
        node * prev;          
};

class LinkedList
{
public:
        LinkedList();
        ~LinkedList();

        void add(char ch);
        bool find(char ch);
        bool del(char ch);
        void display(
private:
        node *head;
};
```

Declaring the structure inside the class definition as a private declaration makes the structure type invisible for the users of the linked list.